On a Linux machine with JDK 11 that is used for development, how should I satisfy OpenOffice's requirement for JRE?
On a Linux machine that has JDK 11 installed, what should I do to allow OpenOffice to run?
As it stands right now, it throws this error:
/opt/openoffice4/program/soffice: line 121: 18205 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) "$sd_prog/$sd_binary" "$@"

java -XshowSettings:properties -version shows this:
java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.7.10-0.fc30.x86_64

This machine previously had JavaSE 8 JDK installed, and OpenOffice worked. Then Java SE JDK was wiped clean, and JDK 11 installed. Since then OO did not work.

how did you install these JREs? And OpenOffice? this all sounds like you shouldn't have removed the JSE8 JDK. Why did you do that? JDKs can coexist without any problem. How did you "wipe it clean", technically?

According to Apache, OO works with Java 11. Is that not true?

could you address the questions I've asked? "Works with" does not mean "your installation was linked against"

All install/remove operations were done with respective dnf commands. If OO does not work with Java 11 then I will use a different product.

again, you can have multple JREs installed in parallel, no problem, the packaging / DNF manages that for you.

Now, this is strange. Why do you so insist on me having to install a long-obsolete version of Java that has multiple vulnerabilities???

because it seems that is the one your openoffice works with…

There is no "my" OO. There is Apache OO. They build and distribute it, having written that it is compatible with Java 11.

yes, but the concrete build you have doesn't seem to be. We're turning in circles here: your OO doesn't work without the specific JNI it was built against, and you don't want to install that. OK, then, don't run OO.
